# In what way does Chrome Devtools log objects asynchronously? (in React Native specifically)

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous

I've read in a few places that Chrome Devtools logs objects asynchronously; that it logs the object but then updates the content of that log if the object changes asynchronously. I'm trying to understand exactly what this means, particularly with React Native. For example, in the following code:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  console.log(prevProps);
  this.setState({
    a: !this.state.a
  })
}
```

Here I try to console log the prevProps object, and then I update the state in order to trigger componentDidUpdate again. In Devtools, it repeatedly logs a *reference* to prevProps, but you're not able to expand it. I understand that this mean Devtools is loading references to the prevProps objects synchronously but the objects themselves are loaded *asynchronously*, and in this case that asynchronous loading never occurs.

So what I want to know is, is this a React Native thing or a Devtools thing? Is the fact that I'm updating the component recursively preventing prevProps from being assigned a value? Or is prevProps being assigned a value every time in React Native, and it's just in Chrome Devtools that the object values aren't being loaded? Any insight would be appreciated, thanks!